# view is different on canvas and on simulator

Tags: objective-c

[image: pic]

Look at the titles of the buttons. Also the placing of the 1 at the bottom.
Any idea what can cause that? (All I did was to drag and drop and wrote some simple calc code)

Answer (score 2):

In your picture, there are blue lines to the bottom and left of your `1` button. This means that your button is aligned to the bottom left of the screen.

The rest of your buttons are probably aligned with the top of the screen. This means that if height of the screen changes, your buttons will not line up. If you align the button to the top of the screen you shouldn't have this issue.

You can change the alignment by moving the button to the top of the screen so that the blue line is at the top and then dragging it back down to where you want it, or you can change it in the `Size Inspector`.

As for the issue of missing titles, it looks like somehow the buttons with missing titles have strange constraints that cause the titles to disappear when the screen is getting laid out. I was able to get rid of the issue by deleting all but the first row of buttons, selecting that first row and duplicating it 4 times for the other rows. This ensures that all the buttons are lined up perfectly. A couple of your buttons had a width of 71 instead of 64 which might have been causing them to be laid out poorly.

Comment: How does that explain the missing title on some of the buttons?

Comment: It doesn't, I missed that part. I guess that issue could be caused by those buttons being modified in your ViewController. I'd try recreating those buttons.

Comment: That's really strange. The 1 button with the blue lines is actually a copy paste from it self. On the simulator it is showing the right title BUT if i'll delete the "bad" 1 button and keep the good one in the next simulator its title will be missing again so recreating the buttons doesn't really help.

Comment: You could always create each button separately.

Comment: I just did. For every 3 buttons i create one comes out with a weird title on the simulator. This is really strange.

Comment: I'm still getting strange titles here and there on my buttons. I wonder what is causing this. Couldn't find anything related online